# Running an animation in the foreground that does not interfere with regular user input

Tags: android

I am developing an application whereby an animation will play in the foreground without disrupting the users normal operations.  The application should load at startup so there is no need for the user to actually open the Activity.

1) Load an application at startup.

2) Have an Activity running with a transparent background that does not block normal input from the user.

Can I get suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Load an application at startup

You need a receiver for this. Create a class like this:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        // start your activity here

    }

}
```

You have to register your "BootReceiver" in your android manifest like this:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".BootReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And make sure that you set the neccessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, clear answer - that solves the first part of the question

Comment: The second part difficult. Search for "Android system overlay" at stackoverflow.